# Verbal and Non-verbal Negation

Tags: negation

'He knows not the truth'

I was studying about Clausal Negation and then suddenly this sentence came to my mind.
Now I am confused of what category it is. It is a **verbal Negation** or a **Non-verbal Negation**?

I have read some previously answered question and I got from there  that it is archaic, prevalent in earlier times and mostly used in poetic sense.

Comment: This is [related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/483508/is-know-not-grammatically-correct/483512). You have the verb "know" and the negation "not", so it's a verbal negation, but an archaic one.

Comment: In different grammar resource I read that for verbal negation 'do' form is necessary except in cases like Subjunctive clause. So, it's still grammatically correct?

Comment: It is certainly correct, but it is as you say, poetic and antiquated. You do encounter it still today in discourses for oratoric purposes.

Comment: "Not" does not modify "the truth", i.e. "not the truth" is not here a constituent. "Not" can only modify "knows", so this is a case of verbal negation, albeit it a very old-fashioned one. In today's English we would say "He doesn't know the truth"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subclausal negation and clausal negation: "not an uncommon mistake" vs. "a not uncommon mistake"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167129/subclausal-negation-and-clausal-negation-not-an-uncommon-mistake-vs-a-not-u)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for suggesting me the question. It is related to the topic of negation. It helped me to better understand how negation works.

Comment: The linkes questioin is related, but in my view not a duplicate, because the specific form "He knows not" or "{Pronoun} {verbs} not" is not covered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an antiquated form of verbal negation. Saying "*he knows not*" is basically the same as saying "*he does not know*". I wouldn't call it 'archaic' because, although not used in modern, informal speech, "know not" is occasionally still used - usually for poetic reasons, when quoting famous texts, or as part of some well-known idioms. For example, two quotations from the King James Bible (originally written in early modern English) have become quite well known idioms - "*they know not of what they speak*", and "*judge not, lest ye be judged*".

However there are other structures where it is still used and not entirely uncommon - for example, we say "I have not..." just as much as "I don't have...", and some use the expression "*haves and have nots*" to refer to the wealthy and the poor.

Comment: It is obligatory with auxiliaries, but only when they are used as auxiliaries: _*I didn't it_ is not grammatical for most people. But in most varieties of English, _be_ uses this even when it isn't an auxiliary, but a lexical verb. The case with _have_ is more complicated. When I was growing up in England in the 60s, _have_ did not take "do"-support: We said _have you (got)_ and _I haven't (got)_ (the "got" was normal in informal contexts). _Do you have?_ and _I don't have_ were things that Americans said, we didn't. But this has changed: _Have you got?_ is common, but _Do you have?_ commoner.